# EXCEL Graphs - change the graph TYPE dynamically

Tags: excel, graph, vba

Wanted a way to change a graph type dynamically( without using VB script, is it even possible?) - say from bar to line or pie.

this will be triggered when a user clicks on a radio button or a drop down or any other way.

Beginner,Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is create a simple chart, record a macro, and change the chart to several different types. Look at the recorded macro and you'll see the code you need to change the chart dynamically.

Here are a couple of examples that change the chart type, assuming your chart is called "Chart 1":

```
Sub ApplyPieChart()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
End Sub

Sub ApplyBarChart()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
End Sub
```

You can then assign these macros to a button, a hyperlink, or whatever else you want.

Note that you can't change chart types with formulas. You will need to use VBA.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you can't do what you're asking. You can't change chart types with formulas, and you can't have anything happen if a user clicks a radio button without VBA.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include the fact that you don't want to use code to change the chart type.